# Wordpress htaccess issue with existing file

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wp blog where I have some categories, pages, posts and so. This is the URL schema:

mysite/category/category_name

mysite/category_name/post_name

Everything is working fine, but now I'm facing a problem with a new category named "php":

On the WP root directory, there is a file named "php.ini" which I've noticed is created automatically by my hosting provider, to allow setting custom php directives on the site.

The problem is that now, all the urls that begin with /php/whatever, are returning a 404 error.

This is the .htaccess content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#some redirects from renamed posts...
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I think that the problem is on this condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, because if I rename the php.ini file, everything works fine. 
I think that if the url begins with php/ and the file php.ini exists, it doesn't process the rule as the condition is not true, even though the url is not actually requesting the file.

I've tried to add some workaround like:

```
RewriteRule ^php/(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

But it's not working. I've tried with several ways but I must be doing something wrong, because I'm always getting a 404 error. It seems like the rule that I'm setting is not being executed, likely if the regex is not met.
Also I've tried to redirect all petitions with a non-static file extension like this:

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|css|js)$ /index.php [L]
```

And this actually worked but then I'm not able to acces to wp-admin for instance.

Do yo have a queue of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Eventually I've "solved" the problem just by renaming the php.ini file to php5.ini. I've noticed that the server is still reading the config and now the .htaccess rules are working. However, the same rule works or not depending on the existence of this file, which I don't think makes sense, as I don't have any condition regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see if it helps.

Download a copy of your .htaccess and then delete the one on the server after doing this go to settings -> permalink and change to default or if on default change to another and save then change back to default and save and after you have done this change back to custom or postname or what you would like to use.

This generates a new .htaccess file and can sometimes correct the old one if an issue comes up. I also have a php.ini file and never seen this issue but then I have never made a php category.

Good luck!